# Should og:image and og:url put in <meta> or <link>?

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, rdfa

For `og:image` and `og:url`, since they have URL, can I place them in a `link` tag instead of a `meta` tag, and is it preferable?

Also what is the difference in using these two tags w.r.t. `og:image` and `og:url`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about other major consumers of the OGP so this might not be a problem for your case, but if you plan to implement it for Facebook,

### stick to meta tags.

Doing a quick live test with the [open graph debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) and fiddling with the `og:` tags, it appears that facebook only recognizes them if they are placed in `<meta>`s.

#### Try it

If you create an empty HTML file with a single `og:url` tag in its `<head>` section, upload it to any URL and run it through the debugger above, both

```
<link rel="og:url" href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
```

and

```
<link property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
```

*edit* or, as suggested in the comments

```
<link property="og:url" href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
```

will fail to parse and return the original URL, while

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
```

parses correctly and returns the contents of The Rock on IMDb instead. At the end of the day semantics are nice, but working code is even better.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am following meta for url with respect to open graph.

Comment: For the `link` element, you have to use the `href` attribute instead of the `content` attribute. So it should be `<link property="og:url" href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />`. Unfortunately I can’t test it because their debugger requires an account.

Comment: Good point, although `property` looks just as awkward on it. Anyway, to be sure I've tested it with `<link property="og:url" href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />` as you suggested but it doesn't parse either. Seems like `meta` is the only accepted tag.

Answer (score 2):

You **must** use `link` instead of `meta` if the value is a URL.

From the [definition of the `meta` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element):

> The `meta` element represents various kinds of metadata that cannot be expressed using the […] `link` […] elements.

But a URL can of course be expressed using a `link` element (as it’s its purpose).

If you use a `meta` element for a URL value, RDFa parsers would extract a string value instead of a URL value. This also means that they wouldn’t be able to apply relative references against the base URL.

#### Example

Let’s say these elements are in a document with the URL `http://example.com/foo`:

```html
<link property="schema:url"    href="/bar" />
<meta property="schema:url" content="/bar" />
```

The value from the `link` element is the URL `http://example.com/bar`.
The value from the `meta` element is the string `/bar`.

#### However, in the case of OGP …

The examples in [OGP’s documentation](http://ogp.me/) use the `meta` element for URL values; there is no example with a `link` element.

While this means that many of their examples are invalid HTML+RDFa, and RDFa parsers will extract strings instead of URLs in those cases,
it *may* be the case that Facebook (or any other consumer) isn’t actually using RDFa to parse the content, and it *may* be the case that they don’t support `link` elements.

Note: These are just possibilities, judging from the quality of their documentation. I don’t have any experience/insight, as I don’t use Facebook. So you might want to test it with Facebook if you care about their OGP-based features.

Comment: I was concerned with open graph for now. Though your answer gave me insights on RDFa parsers which I am planning to implement next. Thanks for the answer.