# Is RDFa `<meta>` without a `name` attribute compatible with HTML5?

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, rdfa

RDFa introduced a [`property` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-core/#s_syntax) for the `<meta>` element, and the W3C even [recommends this as an extension to HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-rdfa/#extensions-to-the-html5-syntax). Facebook's [Open Graph](https://ogp.me/) protocol, for example, uses the RDFa `property` attribute like this (example from the Open Graph site):

```html
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<title>The Rock (1996)</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
…
```

However the HTML5 specification seems to prohibit this usage. I'm not talking about whether it allows the `property` attribute; I'm referring to its explicit prohibition of the `content` attribute without a `name` attribute for [the `<meta>` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element):

> If either `name` or `http-equiv` is specified, then the `content` attribute must also be specified. Otherwise, it must be omitted.

Isn't this in direct conflict with current RDFa usage such as in Open Graph? The HTML5 specification seems to require the presence of a `name` attribute as well here.

Answer (score 4):

The W3C Recommendation "HTML+RDFa 1.1" [extends](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-html-rdfa-20150317/#extensions-to-the-html5-syntax) the HTML spec (you can find [all extensions](https://w3c.github.io/html-extensions/) in a W3C Note).

This extension changes HTML’s conformance requirements for the `meta` element:

> If the RDFa `@property` attribute is present on the `meta` element, neither the `@name`, `@http-equiv`, nor `@charset` attributes are required and the `@content` attribute MUST be specified.

---

So, these two HTML+RDFa elements are valid:

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
```

(The other two `meta` elements are invalid, because they have URL values, for which [the `link` element must be used instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41916286/1591669).)

Comment: I understand the concept of extending a specification, but I don't understand how it is possible to change an absolute requirement ("must be omitted") of the specification; otherwise, there is no way to validate against the specification, as any "extension" could change any part of the specification. It's like a Java class indicating that the `fooBar()` method has `public` visibility, and then a subclass coming along and trying to override the method with visibility `private` (see [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)). Can an "extension" reverse a prohibition?

Comment: @GarretWilson: HTML consumers (e.g., conformance checkers) aren’t required to support extensions. If they do support the extension, they adapt the conformance requirements in total; if they don’t support the extension, they will consider the document to be invalid even just because it has the `property` attribute, whether or not the `name` attribute is also specified. -- Extensions could be understood to be optional changes to the whole HTML spec, for which it was decided (e.g., for organizational/usability/stability reasons) that it would be better to have them in separate documents.